# SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal

Tags: python-3.8

This is my code:

```py
H, M = input().split(' ')
if H == 0 and M < 45:
    H = 23, M = 60 - (M-45)
elif M < 45:
    M = 60 - (M-45)
else:
    M = M - 45
print(H, M)
```

And this is the error message. I do not understand how 23 is not "literal".

```
H = 23, M = 60 - (M-45)
    ^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal
```

Comment: I realized late input number is a constant

Comment: There are no constants as such in Python - you are free to override `H` and `M` with any new value, even of a different type. So your issue is not related to constants.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put multiple statements on one line (which is not recommended because it typically makes the code less readable), you need to separate them with a `;` (semicolon), not a `,` (comma):

```py
>>> a = 0, b = 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: cannot assign to literal
```

```py
>>> a = 0; b = 1
>>> a, b
(0, 1)
```